# Embed IF formula within VLOOKUP

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have the following `VLOOKUP` formula working:

```
=VLOOKUP(B8,PAGE!$A$1:$G$27,$B$3,FALSE)
```

I would like to insert this `IF` formula for the range lookup: `=IF(B8="KS",TRUE,FALSE)` so that the `FALSE` is swapped for `TRUE` only where the text "KS" is present in `B8`.

However, when I combine the two giving:

```
=VLOOKUP(B8,PAGE!$A$1:$G$27,$B$3,(=IF(B8="KS"),TRUE,FALSE))
```

it doesn't work?

Please note "KS" is not a column reference, just the text I am searching for.

Comment: try removing the = before the IF and some extra parenthesis too: write the IF part this way: `IF(B8="KS", TRUE, FALSE)`

Comment: False in Vlookup means exact match and True means less or equal to and column A should be sorted ascending, now can you explain what you need and please show an example

Comment: @yass: mmmh... good doubts. Maybe Emily G only needs to get a TRUE if "KS" is in the range she is looking for? In that case a simple `=IF(COUNTIF(PAGE!$A$1:$G$27,"KS")>0;TRUE;FALSE)` would do